# Can't connect to WiFi but Sees SSIDs: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN, Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, 4.15.0-43-generic

Tags: networking, drivers, intel

```
1. Some basic informatiom
a. Dell Studio 1555
b. Linux kernel version

   dave@dell:~$ uname -r
   4.15.0-43-generic
c. Ubuntu
   dave@dell:~$ lsb_release -a
   No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
    Release:        18.04
    Codename:       bionic
```

2. I ran this and found out that the wifi controller is an Intel WiFi Link 5100.

   dave@dell:~$ lspci -nnk | grep "Network controller"
   04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 [8086:4232]
3. I believe my driver is driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-43-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692

from the partial output of running  sudo lshw

```
*-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: WiFi Link 5100
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                logical name: wlp4s0
                version: 00
                serial: *********************************
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-43-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:26 memory:f8000000-f8001fff

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 [8086:4232]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN [8086:1321]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

I looked at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsIntel but didn't see my exact wifi card listed so maybe that means it doesn't work with Ubuntu.(The page list Intel PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] and iwlagn driver but my card is not designated "AGN [SHILOH].

3. My issue is different than what others have posted. My WiFi can be turned off and on. I can see many broadcast SSID including my own. Whenever I try and connect to it I get popup box error saying "activation of network connection failed

Just to show that the hardware is on at least to receive I did:

```
dave@dell:~$ nmcli d wifi list
IN-USE  SSID                           MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY         
        --                             Infra  36    405 Mbit/s  84      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2        
        xxxxxxxxxxx                    Infra  36    405 Mbit/s  82      ▂▄▆█  --               
        yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy         Infra  9     195 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        mynetwork                      Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2        
        zzzzzzzzzzzz                   Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  65      ▂▄▆_  --
```

My wireless network is shown.

I also have a Dell D560 running Mint (latest version as of (12/28/2019 and updated) and can connect to my wireless network. Of course it has a different network card/driver/firmware (driver=iwl3945 driverversion=4.15.0-43-generic firmware=15.32.2.9 ).

I looked at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsIntel but didn't see my exact wifi card listed so maybe that means it doesn't work with Ubuntu.(The page list Intel PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] and iwlagn driver but my card is not designated "AGN [SHILOH].

So I am at a loss right now. I seem to know what is in the laptop and the wireless driver but don't know what to change in terms of setup and/or software. I don't think it is broken hardware.

I guess I could install Mint on the Studio laptop and see if that works as it does on another laptop.

Any ideas?

Dave

Got it to work with USB module.

I removed the wireless card as it was useless.  I wasn't able to locate any indication it could be made to work. Thanks to all the provided information and kept me from going down a rabbit hole with no way out.

I was able to use an external USB adapter and get WiFi working I bought an OURLiNK Nano USB Wireless Adapter 600Mbps from Amazon (~$10). I then did this:

sudo apt purge rtl8812au-dkms
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
sudo cp -r rtl8812au  /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2
sudo dkms add -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms install -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2

I found this at:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2375603&p=13705226#post13705226

After a reboot the WiFi connection was made. I did have to add DMKS to the system as it was not loaded.

Comment: The card is problematic, to say the least. As you can imagine, there are many questions about it here: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=intel+5100.

Comment: It may just be easier to get a new card or perhaps an external USB WiFi adapter. They don't stick far out of the USB port and are cheap, under $10 as I recall from a Windows experience. Not sure if there are easy drivers for them either though.

Comment: I removed the wireless card as it was useless.  I wasn't able to locate any indication it could be made to work. Thanks to all the provided information and kept me from going down a rabbit hole with no way out.